# heatmap.2 dendrogram wrongly reorder

Tags: r, heatmap, gplots

I have created a heatmap using gplot package heatmap.2 command,I want to seperate case and control group of my gene sample data.But dendrogram mixed one of my control sample column to case sample group.How can I reorder it?

I used the below code

```
heatmap.2(DEGs_count_data_M_L, scale="row", dendrogram="row",col=mycol, cexCol=2, density.info="none", key=T, keysize=0.75, key.par = list(cex=1.5),trace="none",labRow =c(NA), margins=c(12,5))
```

I tried to seperate case and control sample group in same heatmap.

Comment: Please add in some of your data that you are working with.